# Access Database query analyzer

Tags: ms-access

Where is the query analyzer in Access Database?

Comment: Tutorial 4 U: http://techonthenet.com/access/tutorials/passthrough/basics01.php

Comment: i meant to say that where is query analyzer in the access database..

Comment: Edit your question instead of indicating this in comment.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "query analyzer"?

Answer (score 5):

If you by query analyser you mean like SQL servers’ show execution plan, there is no direct relation however you can you the jet showplan switch to display what the actual execution plan is. Here is a link on its usage

https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-5064388.html

Answer (score 4):

[Microsoft Access for Beginners— Part III: Writing the Queries](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access/HA102473131033.aspx)

Comment: @okw, link is dead.

Answer (score 2):

Access beginners should start by using the query designer. This is a visual tool that lets you visually create joins and filters etc. In Access 2007 and later query design is invoked on the create tab. Access is not ideally suited to manually writing your own SQL, certainly not if you're a newcomer to Access's own SQL dialect. You can do that but you'll find it quite frustrating. Access's query design capabilities are one of the main reasons to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You can:

- write the query in any source code that interacts with Access' DBO, ODBC, etc. interfaces;
- store queries in the Queries section of the design view;
- execute ad-hoc queries using third-party tools like [Visual Access](http://www.dqwest.com/vaccess.htm) or other similar products (including many open-source ones).

Comment: Oracle SQL Developer is another one of those 3rd party tools

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a database open Open the query window it creates queries graphically there is a sql window option available once you have the query view open.

Comment: i am using nothwind be database.. in the view, there list data sheet view, pivot table, pivot chart,and design view.. but there is not query..

Comment: The queries are in the design view.

Answer (score 0):

In Access 2010, in the ribbon, click Database Tools, select Analyze Performance from the Analyze group. Select the Queries Tab in the dialog box that appears.

Answer (score 0):

There is something very like Query Analyser for MS Access now:
https://www.arrow-of-time.com/AXF.aspx

(disclosure: this is my product)